# How to define the size of plot area with Core Plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I wanna personalize the size of plot area,because I found the plot area was too small so the percentage numbers were partly visible.Also I don't want to rewrite a CPTTheme class,so any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided the sufficient information and the code in this question . But I think you can use the padding for that like :

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom=25;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft=40;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight=20;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop=20;
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];
```

Answer (score 0):

A theme is just a convenient way to set a lot of appearance properties (line styles, fills, etc.) all at once. You can start by setting a theme and then changing some of the properties, or skip the theme and start with the defaults.

Comment: Thanks,I'd like to start with the defaults.